# map or forEach on array to manipulate value and generate a new array

Tags: javascript, angular, functional-programming

I typecasted formArray into an array which contains two controls (basically its looks like array but its an iteratable object), after that I use `forEach` on it to manipulate object property and generate a new array

```
(Array.from(this.createCandyPixelForm.value.urlRows)).forEach(x => {
  newArray.push(x);
  if (x['url'] == (null || ' ' || false)) {
    x['url'] = 0;
  }
})
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What does `urlRows` look like? What is the expected output? What is not working with the code you have currently? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: `(null || ' ' || false)` will always evaluate to `' '`

Comment: urlRows is a formArray which contains two controls url and http, after consoling urlRows it seems like array but after checking its type its an object

Answer (score 2):

You could map new independent objects to `newArray`, with a check for `url` property and replacing falsy values with zero

```
newArray = Array.from(
    this.createCandyPixelForm.value.urlRows,
    x => Object.assign({}, x, { url: x.url !== ' ' && x.url || 0 })
);
```

Answer (score -1):

After doing certain experiments on code I got the answer which I want. Maybe I was not able to ask properly. So here is what I did :
I created an array from formArray "urlRows" then manipulated the value of "httpsOnly" property for all objects in that array.

```
const newArray = this.createCandyPixelForm.value.urlRows;
        newArray.map(x => {
            console.log("x is", x);
            if (!x.httpsOnly) x.httpsOnly = 0;
            else x.httpsOnly = 1;
        })
```